# Java: Why generic class does not enforce same type?

Tags: java, generics

I have:

```
    public final class SomeClass<L, R>{
    ....
    }
```

If I do:

```
    public final class SomeClass<L, R>{
    ....

    public someMethod(Object obj)
    {
    SomeClass other<L, R> = (SomeClass<L, R>) obj;
    ....
    }
    ....
    SomeClass<String, String> firstObject = new SomeClass<String, String>();
    SomeClass<Integer, Integer> secondObjec = new SomeClass<Integer, Integer>();
    firstObject.someMethod(secondObject );
    ...
```

It does not throw casting exception, even if the `L` and `R` types are different from `firstObject` to `secondObject`.
Why?

Comment: I don't see a generic class here...

Comment: the less and greater were not escaped:) look again, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will compile because you pass an object as a parameter, and cast it explicitly into `SomeClass<L, R>`. Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this will work at runtime as long as you pass any instance of `SomeClass`, because all generic types will have disappeared by then. I'm guessing you're getting a `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to SomeClass<String, String>` warning during compilation (unless you specified `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`).

To avoid this, you'll have to specify the type of the object you're allowed to pass as a parameter, doing for instance:

```
public someMethod(SomeClass<L, R> obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generics in Java are checked by the compiler.  It is not taken into account at runtime.